# ocLazyLoad does not load controller, How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oclazyload

I'm new to Angular Programming, I found a problem about using ocLazyLoad.

First I imported ocLazyLoad to my app. But console occurs these error.

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ABController' is not a function, got
>   undefined

How should i do because i need handle some backend data from controller. Suppose the console need to show "123". This is my code.

Index.html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="example" ng-app="LazyLoadTest" ng-controller="TestController">
        <div ng-controller="ABController"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
            app.controller("TestController", function($scope, $ocLazyLoad, $compile) {
                $ocLazyLoad.load("js/test.js").then(function() {
                    console.log('loaded!!');
                }, function(e) {
                    console.log('errr');
                })
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

main.js

```
var app = angular.module("LazyLoadTest", ["oc.lazyLoad"]);
```

test.js

```
app.controller('ABController', function($scope){ console.log("123"); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case i didn't overlook anything: 
you forgot to include test.js into your index.html...

Comment: Oh, Thx, that's it. =D

Comment: Are you serious :O? he is trying to use $ocLazyLoad. If you load 'test.js' into your index.html... it would be like non using $ocLazyLoad

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
angular.module("LazyLoadTest").controller('ABController', function($scope){ console.log("123"); });
```

in test.js